# how to read encrypted_value in chrome cookie file

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Chrome cookies on windows machines are stored in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`. To read the file I installed sqlite database browser. I have successfully read all values except `encrypted_value`, because it is encrypted.

[image]

How do I read `encrypted_value`? Which encryption scheme is used and what is used as a key?